# Javascript : why copy value but not change

Tags: javascript

I have this setter, but I don't know why set value and it doesn't change :

```
    this.setHead = function(head){
        console.log('Head: x:'+this.getHead().getX()+' y:'+this.getHead().getY());
        console.log('temp Head: x:'+head.getX()+' y:'+head.getY());
        this.head = head;
        console.log('Head: x:'+this.getHead().getX()+' y:'+this.getHead().getY());
    }
```

And the result in Chrome log is :

```
Head: x:5 y:10 // old value
temp Head: x:1 y:7 //temporary value decide to copy
Head: x:5 y:10     // and the new valụe : NO CHANGE
```

I have read that Javascript pass object by reference, I don't know does it difference with Java. If not, I don't know why happen that. Please tell me.

Thanks :)

@ Edited : I have add a line for log, and see strange result :

```
console.log('Head: x:'+this.head.getX()+' y:'+this.head.getY());
Head: x:1 y:7
```

It's strange, because I think it should be same with below line but It don't

> console.log('Head: x:'+this.getHead().getX()+'
>   y:'+this.getHead().getY());

And my `getHead()` is :

```
this.getHead = function() {
            return head;
}
```

Comment: `this` inside `setHead` it's probably not what you think it is...

Comment: Add `console.log('Head: x:'+this.head.getX()+' y:'+this.head.getY());` at the bottom and post what you get.

Comment: Show us the `getHead` function, the `head` object you pass in and eventually the full "class" code.

Comment: @robbrit oh, As you said, when i test your code, I meet strange result. Please tell me ( i have edited my post)

Comment: Have you tried `alert` or other browsers? Always `alert` when you meet a supposed `console.log` bug.

Comment: @Bergi I I have edited my post.

Comment: Your `.getHead` doesn't make any sense. Shouldn't it be `return this.head`?. `this.head` and `head` are separate things.

Comment: @Esailija  but I declare : `var head = something` not `this.var = something`.

Comment: @hqt you assign `this.head`, yet your `getHead()` returns `head`, whatever that refers to. It's not `this.head` for sure. Don't confuse variables and object properties, use variables for short-lived method local state (such as `var i = 0` for iteration) and object properties for long-lived object state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't pass anything by reference, setting `this.head` doesn't magically make `head` refer to something else (which is what by reference implies)

Your `.getHead()` method returns `head`, not `this.head`, so the assignment doesn't affect `getHead()` at all. They refer to different objects.

Try this:

```
this.getHead = function() {
    return this.head;
}
```

---

Basically what you have is most likely:

```
function Ctor( head ) {

    this.getHead = function() {
        return head;
    }

    this.setHead = function( head ) {
        this.head = head;
    }

}
```

the `setHead` sets object property, where as `getHead` returns the `head` variable passed to the constructor when initialized.

To avoid this confusion you should just stick to object properties and prototypes and it's all very simple:

```
function Ctor( head ) {
    this.head = head;
}

Ctor.prototype.getHead = function() {
    return this.head;
};

Ctor.prototype.setHead = function(head) {
    this.head = head;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var o = function(){
  var self = this; // assign 'this' function to a variable
                   // so that it can be accessed in child functions
  var head = {};

  this.getHead = function(){
   ...
   return self.head;
  }
  this.setHead = function(head){
   ...
   self.head = head;
  }
}
```